# Stepping Through Code is Behaving Very Strange

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got the following code on a Word form with checkboxes. When I check one box I want to clear the others.  So when `R00` is already checked and I check `R01` and I start to step through `sub R01_CheckBox_Click()` it will jump to `sub R00_CheckBox_Click()` and then will step for a few lines and then revert back to `sub R01_CheckBox_Click()`.  I changed it to `_afterupdate()` and works ok.  Can anyone explain why the debugger would behave like it is when used with `_click`?

```
Private sub R00_CheckBox_Click()
   R00_CheckBox = true
   R01_CheckBox = false
   R02_CheckBox = false
   R03_CheckBox = false
   R04_CheckBox = false
End sub

Private sub R01_CheckBox_Click()
   R00_CheckBox = false
   R01_CheckBox = true
   R02_CheckBox = false
   R03_CheckBox = false
   R04_CheckBox = false
End sub

Private sub R02_CheckBox_Click()
   R00_CheckBox = false
   R01_CheckBox = false
   R02_CheckBox = true
   R03_CheckBox = false
   R04_CheckBox = false
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** to enhance the explanation

It's because a checkbox `Click` event is triggered whenever you *change* its state (i.e. its `Value` property), whether you do it on the UI or by code.

Suppose to start with all checkboxes unchecked and you click `R00_CheckBox` one:

It triggers its `Click` event handler which is processed without actually changing the *state* of any checkbox, being `R00_CheckBox` just checked (i.e. set to `True`, that's why you're in its `Click` event handler) while all other checkboxes are already set to `False`

Then you click `R01_CheckBox`:

- it triggers its `Click` event whose first statement is `R00_CheckBox = False`

  but `R00_CheckBox` current *state* is `True`, so this triggers `R00_CheckBox_Click` event.

  then you're by now *suspending* `R00_CheckBox_Click` event processing and starting a new `R00_CheckBox_Click` one

  its first statement is `R00_CheckBox = False`, but `R00_CheckBox` current *state* is `True`, so you change its *state* to `False` and therefore *suspend* current event handler processing and switch to `R00_CheckBox_Click` one

  whose first statement is `R00_CheckBox = True`, and there you go again changing its *state* from `False` to `True` therefore *suspending* current `R00_CheckBox_Click` event processing and starting a brand new one

  the now current `R00_CheckBox_Click` event starts again with `R00_CheckBox = True`, which doesn't change `R00_CheckBox` *state*, so this time it doesn't trigger itself again and proceeds with the next statement which is `R01_CheckBox = False` which however does change the *state* of `R01_CheckBox` and therefore *suspending* current `R00_CheckBox_Click` event and starting a new `R01_CheckBox_Click` one

  the now current `R01_CheckBox_Click` event starts again with `R00_CheckBox = False`, which changes `R00_CheckBox` *state* and triggers `R00_CheckBox_Click` event thus *suspending* itself ans starting another brand new `R00_CheckBox_Click` event ...

  ...and then and then...

You'd **much** better switch to `OptionButton` controls, the behavior of which is exactly the one you want: when you check one of them all the others gets automatically unchecked. without all that recursive event handler calling

you can get their state just by querying their default `Value` property like follows:

```
If Me.OptionButton1 Then ... '<--| check if OptionButton1 control is checked
```

Comment: I see what you are saying but I'm very curios as to why it would step out of the middle of a sub to another sub.  Any idea on why?

Comment: @user3723727 I hope the matter is by now clear to you. If it is please mark answer as accepted. thank you